# Randomly hitting Joblib exception in Sklearn on parallel Grid Search

Tags: scikit-learn

I am running gridSearchCV in parallel with n_jobs > 1, but randomly hit the following crash in joblib:

TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases JoblibException, Exception

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example_sklearn.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "example_sklearn.py", line 76, in main
    ).fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", 
        line 372, in fit for clf_params in grid for train, test in cv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py",             
        line 516, in __call__self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", 
        line 448, in retrieve exception_type = _mk_exception(exception.etype)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/my_exceptions.py", 
        line 61, in _mk_exception__str__=JoblibException.__str__),
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases JoblibException, Exception
```

Any pointers on what this really is, and how I can debug this. Is this a known issue with sklearn

Comment: This is not a known issue, please submit a bug report with the version of scikit-learn, the name and version of your OS and a minimalistic script (with randomly generated data) that triggers the bug at least one out of ten times if it's random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same exception, exactly while using the `GridSearchCV`.

If you look at the exception, it is complaining about not being able to understand how exactly it should choose between two parent classes `JoblibException` and `Exception`. This is a bug in the `joblib` package, that the inheritance is improper.

But other than than, there exist another problem, which is the source of the exception itself. It's getting an exception while `retrieve()`ing, and while passing the exception, you get the error.

The second problem (which is the source of the exception), seems to be fixed in later versions of `joblib`. But `scikit-learn` is still using an old version (I will submit a pull request with the changed file soon).

A temporary workaround would be to install your own version of `joblib` using

```
easy_install joblib
```

and then go to the `sklearn/exterlan` folder, remove/rename the `joblib` folder, and create a symbolic link to your own `joblib` using:

```
ln -s /path/to/joblib joblib
```

**EDIT:** Seems somebody has had already fixed the problem. My version was also old.